# I can't find "Windows Subsystem for Linux" in Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows

I need to activate Linux for a programming course. I have been following the instructions but I don't find the "Windows Subsystem for Linux", though I am using Windows 10.

[image: No option for "Windows Subsystem Linux"]

The developer mode was on. I also tried the PowerShell method. Can anyone kindly help me?

[image: My operating system]

Comment: Your version of Windows 10 (copyright 2016) is [out of support.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet) You should update it to receive security and feature updates. The fact you are on an old and unsupported version is most likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: “ The developer mode was on.” - Developer mode isn’t required to install WSL.  If you are following instructions that indicate it must be enabled then those instructions are out of date.  You are also using a version of Windows 10 that hasn’t been supported for over 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

Your operating system is showing the copyright as 2016. WSL was introduced in the [Anniversary Update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux#Introduction_and_availability).

> WSL is available only in 64-bit versions of Windows 10 from version 1607.

While [other sites](https://medium.com/@gmusumeci/linux-on-windows-totally-how-to-install-wsl-1-and-wsl-2-307c9dd38a36) claim

> WSL version 1 was introduced on the Windows Fall Creators Update Version 1709

If you have 1603 then you will need to update your copy of Windows. Windows 10 is currently at 1909.